Flutter (instance of 'quiz question':type 'quiz question' not a subtype of type 'string')
The issue I am having is that it is not reading it as a string, its giving me the error found above.
instance of 'quiz question':type 'quiz question' not a subtype of type 'string'
The result pages is supposed to return a summary of the answer but its not reading it and returning this error.
results screen
quiz question class
I ran the code, following the tutorial I am currently doing, but while testing the emulator to make sure everything is work as it should. It shouldve returned a results screen of text from the quiz that is being answered
the results screen gave me huge error causing the whole thing to crash

Can u share QuestionSummary and getSummaryData code too ?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
